# Solution-verification || Solve the equation $\{ \frac {3x + 5}{x + 2} \}+ \big \lfloor \frac{3x + 2}{x + 1} \big \rfloor = \frac{25}{9}$

Tags: solution-verification, fractional-part

**Question:**

Solve the equation

$$\left\{ \frac {3x + 5}{x + 2} \right\}+ \left\lfloor \frac{3x + 2}{x + 1} \right\rfloor = \frac{25}{9}$$

where $\lfloor a \rfloor$, $\{a\}$
represents the greatest integer $≤a$, respectively fractional part of $a$.

**My idea:**

Ok, so first I wrote $\frac{3x + 5}{x + 2}= 2+ \frac{x+1}{x+2}$
and $ \frac{3x + 2}{x + 1} = 2+ \frac{x}{x+1}$. From here I got $2$ cases:

1. **If $x$ is positive:** then we got $x<x+1$ and $x+1<x+2$, so:

$$\begin{align}&\left\{\frac{3x + 5}{x + 2} \right\}= \left\{ 2+ \frac{x+1}{x+2} \right\}= \frac{x+1}{x+2}\\&\left\lfloor \frac{3x + 2}{x + 1} \right\rfloor= \left\lfloor 2+ \frac{x}{x+1} \right\rfloor =2\end{align}$$

So we get that: $$\frac{x+1}{x+2} +2 = \frac{25}{9}\:\Longrightarrow\:x= \frac{5}{2}$$

2. **If $x$ is negative:** similary we get $$\left\{ \frac{3x + 5}{x + 2} \right\}= \left\{ 3 - \frac{1}{x+2} \right\}= \frac{x+1}{x+2}$$

We know that $x$ is negative which makes $ 2>\frac{x}{x+1}>1$ and:
$$\left\lfloor \frac{3x + 2}{x + 1} \right\rfloor= \left\lfloor 2+ \frac{x}{x+1} \right\rfloor =3$$
Thus:
$$3+ \frac{x+1}{x+2}= \frac{25}{9}\:\longrightarrow\:x=- \frac{13}{11}$$

Can you tell me if my idea and reasoning are corect? Im not sure of the case were $x$ is negative. Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: By "real part" do you mean "fractional part"?   If so, the standard notation is $\{x\}$.  that is to say, $\{x\}+\lfloor x\rfloor = x$

Comment: @lulu yes this is what i mean

Comment: Did you check that value?  The arithmetic for this sort of problem gets so messy that it's always worth checking.  Unless I am mistaken, your value does not work.

Comment: @lulu yeahhh...i tried now and i got that it doesnt work. But still, where is the mistake?

Comment: Go through each step.  And check your work!  At each stage, try values for $x$ and confirm the result.  On a quick read, I don't see anything conceptually wrong with what you wrote, but the calculation is clearly error prone.

Comment: On a second quick read,  the claim that "$x$ is negative which makes $2>\frac {x}{x+1}>1$ is wrong.  Using your value for $x$, the center value there is $6.5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think mistake is in your cases eg.if $x=-1.9999$ according to your 2nd case you get fractional part equal to $1000$

Simplifying as you have

$$
\{ \frac {x + 1}{x + 2} \}+ \big \lfloor \frac{x}{x + 1} \big \rfloor = \frac{7}{9}
$$

Trivially $\big \lfloor \frac{x}{x + 1} \big \rfloor=0$ since RHS<$1$ and fractional part is always positive

$$
0\le{x\over x+1}\Rightarrow x\in(-\infty,-1)\cup[0,\infty)\\ \ \\
{x\over x+1}\lt1\Rightarrow 0\lt{1\over x+1}\Rightarrow x\in(-1,\infty)
$$

The common region being $x\in[0,\infty)$

Now we have for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$
$$
{x+1\over x+2}=n+{7\over9}\\ \ \\
x={5+18n\over 2-9n}
$$

We have from the first case than $x\ge0$ which gives $n\in[-{5\over18},{2\over9})$ the only integer in this range being $n=0$ corresponding to $x={5\over2}$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! May I ask how did you calculated x here ,, $$
0\le{x\over x+1}\Rightarrow x\in(-\infty,-1)\cup[0,\infty)$$ "?

Comment: oh its a nice trick my prof calls the "wave-curvy" method u split real line at the break points as in where either x+1 or x=0 and then alternate plus minus signs to get where it is positive and negative or u could rigorously use cases to find it

Comment: @IONELABUCIU so i just googled it and its  app legit called the ["wavy curvy method"](https://brilliant.org/wiki/wavy-curve-method/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no negative value that satisfies the equation.

**Claim**: $\lfloor x\rfloor + \{y\} = \frac{a}{b}$ has exactly one solution for $\lfloor x \rfloor$ and $\{y\}$ where $a>b$, $a,b \in \mathbb Z^+$.

Note that $\{y\}$ by definition is $\in [0,1)$. This means $\lfloor x\rfloor \in \mathbb Z^+$ since it is already $\in \mathbb Z$  by definition. Now we can write that $a = \lfloor{x}\rfloor b + \{y\}b$, where the first two individual terms are positive integers and $0\le b\{y\}\in \mathbb Z<b$. By [Euclid's division algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division), the pair $\lfloor{x}\rfloor$ and $\{y\}b$ always exists and is unique -- it is the only possible positive integer pair that acts as quotient and remainder respectively on dividing $a$ by $b$.

With this claim, it follows we can write $\frac{25}{9} = 2 + \frac{7}{9}$ as the only representation as an integer + proper fraction.

Now $\lfloor \frac{3x+2}{x+1}\rfloor=\lfloor 3 - \frac{1}{x+1}\rfloor = 2$. But $3-\frac{1}{x+1}\geq 3$ for $x \le -1$, while $3-\frac{1}{x+1}<2$ for $x \in (-1,0)$. So, the floor part can't equal $2$ for any negative $x$, hence showing there is no negative solution. Your proof for the positive part is fine.